# collapse rows in dataframe w/NA values

Tags: r

I am trying to collapse rows a, b, and c in a dataframe that looks like this:

```
>df1 = data.frame(a=c(1,1,0,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA),b=c(NA,NA,NA,0,1,1,NA,NA,NA),c=c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,1,0,1)) 
   a  b  c
1  1 NA NA
2  1 NA NA
3  0 NA NA
4 NA  0 NA
5 NA  1 NA
6 NA  1 NA
7 NA NA  1
8 NA NA  0
9 NA NA  1
```

into row d, creating a dataframe that looks like this:

```
   a  b  c d
1  1 NA NA 1
2  1 NA NA 1
3  0 NA NA 0
4 NA  0 NA 0
5 NA  1 NA 1
6 NA  1 NA 1
7 NA NA  1 1
8 NA NA  0 0
9 NA NA  1 1
```

Any and all help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
# using data.frame
df1$d <- apply(df1, 1, sum, na.rm=TRUE)

# using data.table
DT <- data.table(df1)
DT[, d := sum(.SD, na.rm=TRUE), by=1:nrow(DT)]
```

Comment: I didn't realize `by` could take rows. Cool stuff!

Answer (score 4):

How about this...

```
df1$d <- apply( df1 , 1 , max , na.rm=TRUE )
df1$d
# [1] 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 1
```

Obviously this assumes that you have either a `1` OR a `0` in each row. If you have both it will always select the 1.

This would also work given the data you posted:

```
df1[!is.na(df1)]
# [1] 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 1
```

Comment: (+1) for the 2nd answer. That should be the marked answer IMHO. Using `apply` and `rowSums` coerces it to a matrix which is not necessary here.

Comment: Thanks both. I guess the usefulness depends on whether the sample data is a true reflection of the full data (i.e. if there is *always* only 1 value).

Answer (score 2):

Another R base solution is using `rowSums`

```
> transform(df1, d=rowSums(df1, na.rm=TRUE))
   a  b  c d
1  1 NA NA 1
2  1 NA NA 1
3  0 NA NA 0
4 NA  0 NA 0
5 NA  1 NA 1
6 NA  1 NA 1
7 NA NA  1 1
8 NA NA  0 0
9 NA NA  1 1
```

or directly `df1$d <- rowSums(df1, na.rm=TRUE)`